# all button click events overwritten by submit button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, submit

I have a master page that contains two image buttons, one for account login and another to search the site. The attached aspx page contains a request form for some freebees with a submit button. All button have click events that run different scripts and then redirect them to their respective pages. The master buttons do not conflict with each other. Search performs a search and login performs a login. However, when the page that contains the request form is loaded in the master page it imposes its URLredirect on the master page buttons, causing a postback for the request form from both buttons. I'm aware this is a known issue with .NET do to the whole page being a webform. I set UseSubmitBehavior to False on all of them, hoping the click events would take precedence, but no change. Anyone have an idea how to stop the submit button from overriding the image buttons? Much Thanks

```
 aspx:Request Form Button
 <asp:Button ID="btSubmit" CssClass="FormBtn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btSubmit_Click"
                    OnClientClick="window.scrollTo = function(x,y) { return true; };" 
                    value="greaselid" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>


 CS:Request Form button event
  protected void btSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var validator = new Recaptcha.RecaptchaValidator
        {
            PrivateKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RecaptchaPrivateKey"],
            RemoteIP = Request.UserHostAddress,
            Challenge = Context.Request.Form[RECAPTCHA_CHALLENGE_FIELD],
            Response = Context.Request.Form[RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE_FIELD]
        };

   //after validation email request is sent and then return to same page

 aspx:Login
  <div id="logonbox_SB">
    <div id="FS_1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" class="LoginLabel1" runat="server" Text="Account Number"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="AcctNum" class="AcctNumTexbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div id="FS_2">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" class="LoginLabel2" Text="Access Code"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="MtrNum" class="MtrNumTexbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="Login1" type="submit" runat="server" class="boxsubmitbtn" src="/resources/buttons/login.gif"
        OnClick="LogInBtn_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
</div>

  CS:Login
  protected void LogInBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string AcctNbr = AcctNum.Text;
        Session["AcctNum"] = int.Parse(AcctNbr);
        string MtrNbr = MtrNum.Text;
        Session["MtrNum"] = MtrNbr;

   //account is verified and redirected to user's account page

  aspx:search
  <div id="SearchForm">

    <asp:TextBox ID="searchQuery" runat="server" size="15" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="GO" src="/RESOURCES/buttons/go_button.gif" value="submit2" style="font-size: 11px;" class="GoButton" alt="Go" OnClick="searchButton_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/> 

   </div>

  cs:search
  protected void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder redirectUrl = new StringBuilder();
        //The URL to your resultpage
        redirectUrl.Append("~/about/search_results.aspx");
        //Add your CSE unique identifier
        redirectUrl.Append("?cx='google_account_nbr'%3Aiylaun_ayf0");
        //Add your advertising location code
        //redirectUrl.Append("&cof=FORID%3A11");
        //The search query
        redirectUrl.Append("&q=" + searchQuery.Text);
        //Redirect to the resultpage
        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl.ToString());
    }
  //user is redirected to search result page
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX for that. Just create a button to send the data from the first div to .. where ever you want to send the info. Then, in the same function, call another AJAX with the information you want. Are you using jquery or something? :)